# Separate LEGO Technic wheel from 3 pin hub

Tags: disassembly, wheel

How to separate a 3 pin wheel hub (part# 92909),

[image: 92909]

from this wheel (part# 44772),

[image: 44772]

in order to replace it with another wheel, such as part# 22969?

[image: 22969]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to elaborate on the answer by Wrzlprmft.  The first thing that went through my mind was, "What is this configuration where the Hub is snapped into a wheel but not into the Portal Axle Housing?"  A curious MOC perhaps?  Because normally the wheel easily pulls off of the hub, when it's attached to the housing.

My first advice for anyone messing around with these pieces is to never try to separate the Hub from the Portal Axle Housing once it's snapped in.  I found out the hard way to not just pull it out.  It does still stay in now, but not as well.

[image]

I was suspicious that this process may be much easier than the original answer made it sound.  Perhaps my reading comprehension is to blame there. I first made a "various obvious variation" of a tool described in the previous answer.  I attempted to make it as simple as possible, prove it's function, and provide a picture for clarity.

[image]

It works just fine, dislodging the pin snaps just enough that the hub can be easily removed.  I then tried the first two ideas that popped into my head for comparison.  I often use whatever is in reach for makeshift removal tools.  The first is simply 2 brick separators prying on either side.  This worked just fine and, much to my satisfaction, sent the hub flying into the air.

[image]

The second "tool" was lazily grabbing 2 axles and pushing them simultaneously, with just my hand, into 2 of the 3 Hub pins with moderate force.  This too worked just fine.

[image]

So to recap:  The original answer remains correct and now has an illustrated proof of concept.  We also learned that jamming anything that fits into 2 of the holes works just fine as well.  And, lastly, not to pull the Hub out of the Axle Housing once snapped in.

Comment: definitely the first tool is the best for avoiding locking it by mistake and ending in the same situation as originally was.

Answer (score 7):

The main trick is to simultaneously push all three pins of the hub:

- If you have another hub, and the wheel allows for this, take it and push carefully from the other side. If both hubs are half-way in, you should be able to pull out both.
- Otherwise, take two [wedge belt wheels](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4185), align them on top of each other, insert a pin into every second hole and repeat the above. There are various obvious variations of this approach using different parts, if you need a longer tool or don’t have the parts available.

Comment: I personally prefer using Technic axles to push out difficult pins.

Comment: @Purplemur: That works nicely for one pin, but here you have many pins. Hence just pushing in one pin with a Technic axle (or something similar) will cause it to tilt and stick. Therefore you need to push all pins simultaneously.

Comment: Then, I'd use one of the hubs with three of these: (Technic, Pin Connector Round 2L) https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62462#T=C with three of these: (Technic, Axle Pin) https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43093#T=C to push the pins out. Or, just use one and maintain some pulling pressure as I released each pin in turn.

Comment: @Purplemur: That’s something I would file under *obvious variation of this approach using different parts* in my second bullet point.